# Heroku add folder to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, flask, heroku, pycharm, pythonpath

Hello) My project has the following structure:

```
app/
  - api/
  - ..some_folders/
  - web/
    start.py
    ...
    some files
    ...
- run.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

Paths in my python code are relative to the app folder, e.g. in the `run.py` I import `from web import start.py`. Therefore, I have the `root` and `root/app` (`app` as the source root). The entry point of the application is `run.py`. Locally, I am able to include source root to the PYTHONPATH using the pycharm run options and the program works as I need.

**My question is:** how can I mark my `app` folder on `Heroku` so that it understands that the application should start from the root folder (where run files are located), while imports should be made relative to the `app` root.

Would be glad for any help